# Count lines in csv-file after submitting in form

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

How could i capture the "nicefile.csv" and count the rows in the file after i submit it with POST from a form? I tried something like `$csvlinecount = count(file('$_FILES[csv]'));` without result. The reason is i have code that counts amout of rows in my database before and after i import the csv-values, but im sorting out duplicate entries. So it would be fun to know if the before number of entries is 100 and after it´s 200, then i know it imported 100 new lines. But if i dont know the amount of lines in the csv-file, i dont know how many it skipped during the import.

```
<?php 

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");

//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {
if ($data[0]) {
    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO wifi (bssid, channel, privacy, ciper, auth, power, essid, latitude, longitude, first_seen, last_seen) VALUES
        (
            '".addslashes($data[0])."',
            '".addslashes($data[1])."',
            '".addslashes($data[2])."',
            '".addslashes($data[3])."',
            '".addslashes($data[4])."',
            '".addslashes($data[5])."',
            '".addslashes($data[6])."',
            '".addslashes($data[7])."',
            '".addslashes($data[8])."',
            '".addslashes($data[9])."',
            '".addslashes($data[10])."' 
        )
    ");
}
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,","));

//redirect
header('Location: index.php/upload?success=1'); die;

}

//Count after import
$after = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wifi");
$num_rows_after = mysql_num_rows($after);


//echo stats
echo "Number of rows before - ";
echo "$num_rows_before";
<br>
echo "Number of rows after - ";
echo "$num_rows_after";

//generic success notice
if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<br><b>Result: Your file is imported!</b><br>"; } 

//Close connection to databse
mysql_close($connect) ; 

?>
```

Comment: `addslashes()` isn't recommended. Instead try [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Or `mysql_real_escape_string()` at the very minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another variable to count number of lines. For instance, like below (see new `$linesCount` variable):

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
$linesCount = 0;
//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {

if ($data[0]) {
    $linesCount ++;
    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO wifi (bssid, channel, privacy, ciper, auth, power, essid, latitude, longitude, first_seen, last_seen) VALUES
        (
            '".addslashes($data[0])."',
            '".addslashes($data[1])."',
            '".addslashes($data[2])."',
            '".addslashes($data[3])."',
            '".addslashes($data[4])."',
            '".addslashes($data[5])."',
            '".addslashes($data[6])."',
            '".addslashes($data[7])."',
            '".addslashes($data[8])."',
            '".addslashes($data[9])."',
            '".addslashes($data[10])."' 
        )
    ");
}
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,","));

//redirect
header('Location: index.php/upload?success=1'); die;

}
```

Also, I would recommend to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function instead of `addslashes`. I always had a lot of problems with that addslashes function and it simply escape slashes when `mysql_real_escape_string` covers more SQL Injection techniques.

But the best would be to forget mysql_* functions (those are deprecated already) and use PDO or mysqli instead

Answer (score 1):

**using the below code you can get number of lines**

```
$upload_temp=$_FILES["school_upload"]["tmp_name"];      
$fileTemp = $upload_temp;    
$lines = file($fileTemp);    
echo count($lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can count the rows you have to split it into rows. Before it is just a long string.

```
$count = count(explode("\r\n", file_get_contents($_FILES[csv][tmp_name])));
```

Comment: When i copy/paste this code into my site and save it(im using Joomla), the slashes from "\r\n" just disappears and i end up with "rn". Any idea why?

Comment: You save it in a file yourself or via an editor inside of joomla?
If it is the second case the slash could be removed via joomla.

Comment: Via the joomla editor. Yes i guess it´s Joomla who removes it. Is there any other way i can write the code and get the same result? Some way that Joomla doesn´t remove for me?
UPDATE: Just tried your code with the slashes going the other way, "/r/n", and joomla keeps it. Would it work the same way?

Comment: No it won't. I am not that familiar with Joomla. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$csvlinecount = count(file('$_FILES[csv]'));
```

sets as param for function file a string not the actual file content.

Try:

```
$csvlinecount = count(file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this without having to iterate through the CSV is to the Linux backend of your server.  From [John Reeve](http://www.myintervals.com/blog/2011/06/21/calculate-the-number-of-lines-in-a-csv-file-using-php-and-linux/):

```
$linecount = exec('perl -pe \'s/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g\' ' . escapeshellarg($_FILES[csv][tmp_name]) . ' | wc -l');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $linecount = count(file($filename));
```